# Interview Question: What is a hashmap?

Tags: hashmap

I was asked this in an interview: *"Tell me everything you know about hashmaps."*

I proceeded to do just that: it's a data structure with key-value pairs; a hash function is used to locate the element; how hash collisions can be resolved, etc.

After I was done, they asked: *"OK, now explain everything you just said to a 5-year-old. You can't use technical terms, especially hashing and mapping."*

I have to say it took me by surprise and I didn't give a good answer. How would you answer?

Comment: I think this is a stupid thing to ask in the interview unless the job is teaching data structures to five year olds.

Comment: Seriously. Even [lambda calculus](http://worrydream.com/AlligatorEggs/) is only good for eight year olds.

Comment: I would apologise for not understanding that I was in the presence of one

Comment: can we assume the 5 year old has 5 years of algorithm experience?

Comment: @WW I think there is a point to this; it used to surprise me how many programmers don't truly understand the concept of hashing.

Comment: I feel bad that they had a 5 year old in an interview about programming. Being that the kid hangs out in technical interviews, I would guess he may have already heard the question more than once and may know what I hashmap is. Therefore your answer seems well enough.

Comment: They were probably trying to find out whether you can explain the essentials of a problem, without going too much into details. It's something I see often and have been doing myself: it seems easier to explain a problem with the technical terms and in detail, but other persons often don't care fore the details but only for the important parts. It can be annoying: in our daily team meetings there two developers that can't just tell the point but always have to tell the whole story even though nobody cares. Eats up a lot of time every day.

Comment: TBH, I often ask people describing a problem to explain it to me like I'm 3, as it cuts out a lot of assumptions about the make about their problem, either because they assume knowledge I don't have about the problem domain, or because they aren't really thinking about the right problem, having already jumped to their own idea of the solution. Apart from getting them to rephrase it better for my sake, it's interesting how it makes them rethink it for themselves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a hash map in programming and where can it be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592043/what-is-a-hash-map-in-programming-and-where-can-it-be-used)

Comment: "I think this is a stupid thing to ask in the interview unless the job is teaching data structures to five year olds. " -- That's a stupid thing to think. It's perfectly reasonable way to explore whether someone is a clear thinker and good communicator.

Comment: Might be better on http://workplace.stackexchange.com :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Lets take the big word book, or dictionary, and try to find the word zebra.  We can easily guess that zebras will be near the end of the book, just like the letter "Z" is at the end of the alphabet.  Now lets say that we can always find where the zebra is inside of the big word book.  This is the way that we can quickly find zebras, or elephants, or any other type of thing we can think of in the big word book.  Sometimes two words will be on the same page like apple and ant.  We are sure which page we want to look at, but we aren't sure how close apple and ant are to each other until we get to the page.  Sometimes apple and ant can be on the same page and sometimes they might not be, some big word books have bigger words.

That's how I would have done it.

Comment: You're describing an sorted index, more than a HashMap.

Comment: You do realize a map is a dictionary right?  The use of the real life dictionary is to explain a data structure to a 5 year old

Comment: The dictionary analogy is wrong though even to a 5 year old.  ZEBRA being "near the end of the book" and requiring scanning is at best O(LogN) and probably closer to linear for a 5 year old.  ZEBRA on page 453 is O(1).  I would use a decoder-ring analogy for the hash function.  You put ZEBRA in your decoder-ring, and the number 453 comes out -- well, then kiddo, the word ZEBRA is on page 453.

Comment: While you are technically right in that a HashMap is a dictionary. Your application is flawed because its too abstract to answer the question. Dictionaries can be implemented with data structures that have no resemblance to a HashMap(trees or even just arrays). Its akin to describing a square by talking about a rectangle.

Comment: Nicely-done. I enjoyed reading it. :)

Comment: @nsfyn55 Jeez there is no escaping you :D

Comment: googling decoder-ring

Comment: Older dictionaries had cut-outs on the page-edges showing where each letter began.  So you could quickly turn to the "Z" section.  That's the "hash" function in a real-world (old school) dictionary.  Once you get to the Z (or E or whatever) section, you've got a sorted list rather than a linked-list of entries but, when explaining to a 5 yr old, that's "close enough".  If the question was really "explain to a non-technical adult" (ex: management), you might have done it differently.  Say, with puppets.  ;)

Answer (score 50):

Rules.  Kids know rules.  Kids know that certain items belong in certain places.  A HashMap is like a set of rules that say, given an item (your shoes, your favorite book, or your clothes) that there is a specific place that they should go (the shoe rack, the bookshelf, or the closet).

So if you want to know where to look for your shoes, you know to look in the shoe rack.

But wait:  what happens if the shoe rack is already full?  There are a few options.

1) For each item, there's a list of places you can try. Try putting them next to the door.   But wait, there's something there already: where else can we put them?  Try the closet. If we need to find our shoes, we follow the same list until we find them. (probing sequences)

2) Buy a bigger house, with a bigger shoe rack. (dynamic resizing)

3) Stack the shoes on top of the rack, ignoring the fact that it makes it a real pain to find the right pair, because we have to go through all of the shoes in the pile to find them. (chaining).

Comment: I googled hashmaps to figure out what they are. This is actually by far the best, generalized account I found. Excellent.

Answer (score 6):

Speaking as a parent, if I had to explain a hashmap to a 5-year-old, I'd say exactly what you said while waving around a chocolate cupcake.

Seriously, questions like this ought to mean "can you explain the concept in plain english", a good heuristic for how well you've internalized your understanding of it. Since it sounds like you get that, the question seems a bit silly.

Comment: I have to +1 this, because I I have indeed explained complicated technical concepts (when chains of "why?" questions have gotten to a certain point) to children by just giving the same answer I'd give a fellow tech (perhaps even upping the complexity) but jumping around excitedly a bit. This often satisfies them.

Answer (score 5):

The pieces of data the map holds can be looked up by some related information, much like how pages can be looked up by the words on them in the index of a book.

The key advantage to using a HashMap is that like an index in a book, it's much quicker to look up the page a word is on in the index than it would be to start searching page by page for that word.

(I'm giving you a serious answer because the interviewer *might* have been trying to see how well you can explain technical concepts to non-techies like project managers and customers. Maybe a hashmap directly isn't so useful, but it's probably as fair an indication as any of translation skills.)

Answer (score 3):

You have a book of blank but numbered pages and a special decoder ring that generates a page number when a something is entered into it into it.

To assign a value:

You get a ID (key) and a message (value).

You put the ID into the special decoder ring and it spits out the page number.

Open your book to that page.  If the ID is on the page, cross out the ID/message.

Now write the ID and message on the page.  If there is already a one or more other IDs with messages just write the new one below it.

To retrieve a value:

You are given just an ID (key).

You put the ID into the special decoder ring and it spits out the page number.

Open your book to that page.  If the ID is on the page, read the message (value) that follows it.