# 1D Array into 2D array (vb)

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I have split the 1d array and i need convert it into a 2d array. The array consists of numbers (scores) and names as results of a numerical test.

```
Dim results1 As String = File.ReadAllText("Z:\scores class 1.txt")

Dim array = Split(results1, " ")

For i As Integer = 0 To array.Length - 1
   Console.WriteLine(array(i))
Next

Console.WriteLine("Would you like these to be sorted? Press 1 for yes, 2 for no")

If Console.ReadLine = 1 Then
   ' do some stuff
ElseIf Console.ReadLine = 2 Then
   ' do some stuff
End If

Console.ReadLine()
```

That is my current code, what do i need to add? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve. Do you want to convert 1D to 2D. Is it NxN matrix,etc. Please be specific.

Comment: I am not very advanced in programming, my 1d arry has  name in cell one then score in cell two and so on, im trying to get it into a 2d array so the score is under the name in the array if u know what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Converting 1D to 2D is possible when you have contigious key/value present to make it as index of array but in your case it is neither. So better option will be to use HashMap/HashTable in general. As per your requirement instead of using 2D array to represent name: value pair you should use a [HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592043/what-is-a-hash-map-in-programming-and-where-can-it-be-used) .

As per your statement in commnets you have an 1D array which holds name:value
i.e

`String arr [] = { "jack", "23", "mat","45", "mike","56" }`

You can better represent it as a [HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592043/what-is-a-hash-map-in-programming-and-where-can-it-be-used) .

```
HashMap<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

hm.add("jack",23);       // it will add score of 23 to name jack i.e "jack" : 23
hm.add("mat",45);
hm.add("mike",56);
```

Now you can easily manipulate any name:value pair

e.g. To get marks scored by  **"mat"** just write **`hm.get("mat")`**

It will output the marks associated with mat i.e **45.**

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim array2((array.Length / 2) - 1, 1) As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To (array.Length - 1) / 2 Step 1
        array2(i, 0) = array(i * 2)
        array2(i, 1) = array((i + 1) * 2 - 1)
    Next
```

This creates a two dimensional array with the values from the 1d array.