# The time complexity of the map function

Tags: time-complexity

I heard the calculation amount of map function is O(1).
But I can't understand the reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a hash map in programming and where can it be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592043/what-is-a-hash-map-in-programming-and-where-can-it-be-used)

Comment: O(1) would be an ArrayList accessing its element with index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, O(1) is the complexity of accesing one item. Array.map() in JS passes the function the current value and iterates through all of them, and takes the return value of the function and inserts it into the new array.

Therefore, the function loops through every object in the array, having a complexity of O(n).

For example:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(function (item) { return item + 1; });
```

Said function takes one item at a time, accessing the array n times (3).

EDIT: Looks like I misunderstood your question, my bad.

Comment: I think OP is referring to a `Map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Ah. My mistake. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: How is this O(1)? That's O(n) when you "iterate through all of them".

Comment: This is wrong. Time complexity for the .map function is O(n). See this useful site for all the different javascript array methods: https://dev.to/lukocastillo/time-complexity-big-0-for-javascript-array-methods-and-examples-mlg

Answer (score 0):

The inbuilt map method shares the input iterable across the CPU cores. For an iterable of size n, the average running time would be Θ(n/num_cpu_cores)