# C++ trying to count how many times a user has entered a specific number

Tags: c++, count, numbers

I am trying to write a program that counts how many times a specific number is inputted by a user from a while loop. Here is the idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool progLoop = true;
    int Number;
    char response;
    while (progLoop == true)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number: " << endl; \
        cin >> Number;
        cout << "Number collected!" << endl;
        cout << "Number of times that number has been entered: " << endl; //IDK how to do this part which is what I'm looking for.
        cout << "Do you want to enter another number?" << endl;
        cin >> response;
        if (response == 'y') 
        {
            progLoop == true;
        }
        else if(response == 'n')
        {
            progLoop == false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way that I can store a  sort of value of how many times that specific number has been entered into the program. Would like to clarify if there are any questions! Thanks! (Modifying my code would be great!)

Comment: One way is to create a vector and every time a new number is inputted, it is pushed back into the vector. Then you can `std::count` that number when you need to check. Another way could be to use an `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: By the way, you accidentally write `progLoop == true;` and `progLoop == false;` in the loop, meaning that even if you type`n`, the loop will still run.

Comment: I just posted the way with the unordered_map, better performance imho

Comment: You don't need the boolean, you can just have a character set to 'y'

Comment: You should also have the usage between bracket (y/n)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592043/what-is-a-hash-map-in-programming-and-where-can-it-be-used):

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number;
    char response = 'y';
    unordered_map<int, int> m; // your hashmap

    while (response == 'y')
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number: " << endl; 
        cin >> number;
        cout << "Number collected!" << endl;
        cout << "Number of times that number has been entered: " << ++m[number] << endl; // preincrement your hashmap at key number
        cout << "Do you want to enter another number? (y/n)" << endl;
        cin >> response;
        response = tolower(response); // give a chance to exit the loop if your user like to use caplock (like Trump)
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, I would either 1) get rid of `m[Number]++;` and use `... << ++m[Number] << ...` instead; 2) change `m[Number]++;` to `int count = ++m[Number];` and use `... << count << ...` instead.

Comment: @Antonin GAVREL You still have the ````progLoop ==...```` in the code. It will not work.

Comment: Edited (nb: no need for count), neither the boolean

Answer (score 0):

*Expanding my comment into an answer*

One way of doing this is to use an `std::vector` and every time a new number is inputted, it is pushed back into the vector. Then you can `std::count` that number when you need to check. In your program, it would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    bool progLoop = true;
    int Number;
    std::vector<int> numCount;
    char response;
    while (progLoop == true)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number: " << endl;
        cin >> Number;
        numCount.push_back(Number);
        cout << "Number collected!" << endl;
        cout << "Number of times that number has been entered: " << std::count(numCount.begin(), numCount.end(), Number) << endl;
        cout << "Do you want to enter another number?" << endl;
        cin >> response;
        if (response == 'y') 
        {
            progLoop = true; // You accidentally used == here
        }
        else if(response == 'n')
        {
            progLoop = false; // You accidentally used == here
        }
    }
}
```